# How important is it to remember correct genders?

Tags: genre

I'd like to try learning French, having failed to do so at school, but one thing that puts me off is the idea of learning word genders.

The idea that a lampshade or a radiator is masculine or feminine seems completely ridiculous and my brain refuses to participate in this game.

If I were to learn French but I got the gender of objects wrong, would what I was saying be understandable by a French speaker?

Comment: It's important, but not indispensable. A French speaker would understand you, sometimes they will be surprised to hear a gender mistake, but still they will understand what you're saying.

Comment: One side-comment: pay attention that noun genders are quite common. It is not only in French but in many languages: Spanish, German, Russian, etc. Roughly half the known languages, if I remember correctly, though I don't know in therms of population. So I would not say it is "completely ridiculous" even if it seems awkward to you as an English speaker.

Comment: A trick to learn the kind of words: use your ears! Learn the words with an adjective that we often encounter with it : "**un** radiateur brûl**ant**" (the gender + the accent on the *û* :-) and " **une** lampe brûl**ant*e***" ... but beware, "*vaste, riche, pauvre*" do not have a gender.

Comment: … en ayant le genre de l’article (concept) ET celui de l’adjectif (perception auditive) vous associez la mémoire du mental et la mémoire émotionnelle.

Comment: The idea that there are irregular forms for the past tense of verbs in English is repellent, I refuse to participate in this game. If i speaked and writed using only regular forms, can I still be understanded?

Comment: @grandtout - I understanding you fine.

Comment: @grandtout - Seriously though, this is a very real block for me. My choice is to learn but get the genders of objects wrong or not bother even trying. What would you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I were to learn French but I got the gender of objects wrong, would what I was saying be understandable by a French speaker?

Yes, of course, assuming the rest of your French is correct enough. Using wrong noun genders is a very common mistake made by people for whom French is not the mother tongue, and especially native English speakers for whom this concept is foreign.

Answer (score 1):

If the gender is uncertain/wrong, context would be the biggest indicator in a conversation. For example, you've almost definitely heard of the "Tour de France" and the "Eiffel Tower." In French, these are <<**Le** Tour de France>> and <<**La** Tour Eiffel>> respectively. Le Tour would be the ride/turn, while La Tour would be the tower.

Regardless, grammatical genders are important in any language using them, unless proper grammar is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

the notion of gender in French is one of the most difficult points to grasp in the language, and especially for the English-speaking world.
French distinguishes the masculine from the feminine whether for people as for "objects". there is also the "neutral" gender *(who is not male nor female*).

below 2 very light description links, but which can be used as a basis.
"le vs la" http://www.frenchtutorial.com/en/learn-french/basics/le_la_les
"genders" https://www.france-pub.com/french-masculine-feminine.php
*in english with french sample*

know that in French for example:  "**une** armoire" (a cupboard) on one side and on the other hand "**un** meuble" (a furniture) on the other, yet a cupboard is a piece of furniture ;) (**une** armoire est **un** meuble)

other sample .. "**un** arbre est dans **la** forêt" (a tree is in the forest) we say "**la** forêt" (a designed forest) and **une** "forêt" (one of forest)

But, "**un** arbre" (a tree) **can't say** "**le** arbre" !
-> "**les** arbre**s**" or "**des** arbre**s**" (trees) is ok (

there are no grammatical global rules *(except for certain cases)*, and it will simply be necessary to know if it is an "**le/un**" or "**la/une**".
this is one of the mistakes (funny for the French) that all non-French speaking foreigners do the most
You learn it n time

Here a review on the knowledge of "gender" at school (9 year olds)
http://ekladata.com/93tBec2fivol3yOFXLCMpdCCwjo/Fiches-Orthographe-CM1.pdf
practice, and get corrected ;)